# Classpath in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am new to Gradle. I have written a JavaCompile task. So, when I didn't specify the classpath in the task it is throwing me an error. In maven, we don't specify the classpath it automatically takes the default location of the dependencies and takes them during compilation. Is it a must to specify the classpath in Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the task needs a classpath set via a property available during the configuration phase.

It isn't common in my experience to declare JavaCompile tasks directly, and when you do it usually means some sort of the special or custom build. In this case you will want full control over the compiler options.

A common motif is for the classpath to be set in terms of a specific configuration:

```
classpath = configurations.compile
```

This is similar in practice to the implicit Maven classpath taken from the dependencies. However, since Gradle config is composed of blocks of Groovy (or whatever) and not contextual XML, you have to tell it from what configuration you want to take the classpath.